# Simple Login using Spring Security and Hibernate

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

My requirement is to validate user id and password from db using spring security and hibernate.

I want to open login.jsp page on first request of user and once the user is validated then only it should redirected to index.jsp.

I tried several options but not able to figure out the correct way of how to do it.

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/jsp/login.jsp"
            default-target-url="/jsp/index.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/jsp/login.jsp?login_error=1" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            invalidate-session="true" />

    </http>

    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.onmobile.otp.db.CustomUserDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="urmService" ref="urmService" />
    </beans:bean>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
package com.onmobile.otp.db;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.GrantedAuthorityImpl;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.onmobile.otp.domain.Permission;
import com.onmobile.otp.domain.User;


public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    URMService urmService=null;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        System.out.println("Inside loadUserByUserName");

        User user = urmService.getUserByUserName(userName);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username :"+ userName + " not found in database");
        }

        UserRole userRole = urmService.getUserRoleByUser(user);
        if(userRole == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(userRole.getRole() == null){
            return null;
        }

        List<Permission> userAuthorities = urmService.getPermissionsByRole(userRole.getRole());
        if(userAuthorities == null){
            return null;
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthoritiesList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(Permission permission : userAuthorities){
            String perm = permission.getPermissionName();
            grantedAuthoritiesList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(perm));
        }
        GrantedAuthority [] grantedAuthoritiesArray = grantedAuthoritiesList.toArray(new GrantedAuthority[grantedAuthoritiesList.size()]);
        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, grantedAuthoritiesArray);
        customUserDetails.setUserRole(userRole);

        return customUserDetails;
    }

    public void setUrmService(URMService urmService) {
        this.urmService = urmService;
    }

}
```

I am getting exception as

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No authentication providers were found in the application context
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.config.NamespaceAuthenticationManager.afterPropertiesSet(NamespaceAuthenticationManager.java:31)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 30 more
```

Please suggest me a where I am going wrong.  Thanks

Comment: Which version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: I am using spring security 2.0.4. This Program i am writing just to learn spring security. So I am fine if you can suggest me some solution and if that solution needs changes in jars version. I searched a lot but I didn't found any website which clearly explains the configuration...please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what caused the error, but I suspect some version incompatibility. Note that you use Spring Security namespace of version 3.1: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.....I tried changing jars but still problem persist. if we forgot the above post and if you can suggest me things from start then also it is fine..Thanks

Comment: can you post web.xml, looks like applicationContext-security.xml not being loaded.

Comment: Update your example with the correct usage of Spring Security 3.0 or 3.1. You cannot mix them.